# java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:8080 an android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/SampleServlet/TestServlet?";
URL url = new URL(con_url);

run in android emualator. but i got the connectexception 
02-20 13:05:08.745: ERROR/Server Connection(230): java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:8080 - Connection refused

please reply me

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

127.0.0.1 is a Android emulated device's own loopback interface.

In other words, you connect to android emulated device (not to your computer) by using 127.0.0.1.

To get connection to your machine with web-server use **10.0.2.2** or real machine IP address (if you have direct access from web).

Use command **ipconfig**(Windows)/**ifconfig**(Linux) to obtain your IP address.

Also see [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) or [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/android_emulator_networkaddresses.html)!

Comment: Actually, I suggest to modify link to point to official documentation - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking