# connection refused when trying to connect to my REST server from android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

consider the following android code and please solve my problem:
There is REST server running on my laptop..i can access that server from my browser and get proper resuts...but now i want to use it from my android emulator that is also running on my laptop using following code..

```
 // String URL = "http://localhost:8080/server/rest/user/1";
 String URL = "http://www.google.com";

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse result = httpclient.execute(request);
```

in emulator when i pass the URL as http://www.google.com , i got proper response in result but when i use my localhost url(the commented one above) i got connection refused....

```
WARN/System.err(901): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
WARN/System.err(901): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:8080 - Connection refused
```

if i run the same url on my browser it works.
 can you tell me why localhost url is not working in emulator..?

Comment: local (machine) host in Android Emulator can be accessed by the IP 10.0.2.2

Comment: Adil I already tried it but that also didn't work..pls help me out.

Comment: Have you read these threads [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495534/java-net-connectexception-localhost-127-0-0-18080-connection-refused/5495789#5495789), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301560/java-net-connectexception-127-0-0-18080-an-android-emulator/2301648#2301648) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905315/error-connection-refused/4905367#4905367)

Comment: thanks Adil for these links but all 3 links are suggesting to replace localhost by 10.0.2.2, that i have already tried and i got this error now    **java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol**

Comment: If you're still facing the issue, feel free to give this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032554/12298875) a try

Answer (score 23):

Ankur, I had the same problem but replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2 worked for me. Also make sure you have added the line 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

within the <manifest> tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Thanks Adil and rogerstone for your responses.

-Ajmal

Comment: Adil, android permission for internet was already there in manifest...coz then only i got response for http://www.google.com..

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614295/connection-refused-when-trying-to-acces-local-webservice-using-android

Comment: Im at a loss. I can get this working from my android tv but cannot from the android tv emulator. My local server is node.... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your url by http://10.0.2.2:8080/server/rest/user/1. This should work.

Comment: It did not work even when i tried replacing localhost with following IP 10.0.2.2 (as suggested  [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)). I also tried accessing it by my absolute IP of my laptop (192.168.1.3) but in vain. However in this case even my browser didn't return me any response.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are not running the connection on main thread

Comment: If you like, your could improve your answer by elaborating a bit. How can one make sure not to run the connection in the main thread? What will be the consequences if one do? How can it be corrected in the code?