# Pushing at Android

Tags: android, http-post, google-cloud-messaging, ioexception

I've made A GCM Application.

I made web sever by Node.js and I checked my POST is working well by using Postman.

So, I am making an app that when button clicked, it posts so GCM Message comes to my device.

and this is my post code.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL+"/push");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("11111", "11111");
    }
```

I don't have any params with my POST so nameValueParams has nothing.

But in my log cat, it shows log.v("11111","11111");

there is an IOException, what is the problem? My manifest includes INTERNET PERMISSION ALSO.

Every example code has that structure but it goes to IOException.

Comment: replace the 2nd argument to your Log.v with `Log.getStackTraceString(e)` and update your question with stacktrace

Comment: Thank you! By doing this, I got "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:52273 refused" error...

Comment: what is `SERVER_URL`, are you testing on emulator ? you dont want `127.0.0.1` which is localhost (android device itself).

Comment: SERVER_URL is LOCALhost. I know what you think. But I found my IP at ipip.kr. but after changing my address, post doesn't work... what do you think? Colleagues said I need Official Server not local server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your development system as the server, you cannot use `localhost` as it will be pointing to your android device itself, not the server.

If you are testing this code on emulator, you can replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2`. As the emulator is running on your development system, it can talk to the server [via emulator internal network](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

If you would like to test this on a phone device, and not on emulator, you either need to have a server accessible from internet, or have your phone and your server be on the same wifi or local subnet. You will also need to configure your server to [allow network connections coming in from different networks, see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015883/connecting-localhost-via-android-connection-to-10-0-2-2-refused).