# insert data to local host xampp

Tags: php, android, eclipse

my app is working perfect when i am saving data to web server,but when i save it on local host database it is giving 
 `Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` error..

here is my code:

```
try
    {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.website.com/exmpl/insertData.php");      //working perfectly
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.1/exmpl/insertData.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");         
    }
```

log cat:

```
01-05 19:02:53.150: E/pass 1(28604): connection success 
01-05 19:02:53.410: E/Fail 3(28604): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**EDIT**
errors if i change the ip address to 192.168.0.123

```
01-06 10:00:37.560: E/Fail 1(4261): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.123 refused
01-06 10:00:37.570: E/AndroidRuntime(4261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

and i am not using async task,,i am extending activity

even tried 192.168.0.123:80 followed [MR.HU'NG](http://imrhung.blogspot.in/2014/03/connect-real-device-to-localhost-using.html)

**Error again**

```
Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Are you testing this app in Phone? If yes then try to run in emulator.

Comment: test your url with web navigator

Comment: yes @ParmarS i am testing it on device not on emulator...am not able to set emulator..

Comment: because i experienced that device does not detect localhost, emulator does.

Comment: so,if we want to save data to localhost then we must use emulator??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of 192.168.0.1/exmpl/insertData.php on the ANDROID DEVICE are not the same of your PC, because, 192.168.0.1 in the DEVICE points to itself, not to you apache server.

You must use the IP of your machine, assigned by the local router, or configure your emulator to use some fixed ip.

Probably, the 192.168.0.1/exmpl/insertData.php are returning something like "page not found".

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is always local, so 192.168.0.1 might very well be the IP assigned to the PC by the router (although I would have guessed it's the router itself, not the client PC). So if phone and PC are in the same LAN, why wouldn't it work..

Comment: @Tiago now i changed the ip address to local ip and updated my question with the errors..please have a look
and i even tried all the solutions provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015883/connecting-localhost-via-android-connection-to-10-0-2-2-refused but nothing worked

Comment: A easy way to test it, is open the browser on the device and type that url there. If it open, it will run ok on your app, if not, the app will go bad too. Check you machine IP on you local network and use it on your code.

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa almost an year.. Your help did worked. the address that worked for me is: " http://192.168.0.130/PrabS/books.php " i.e., System IP address and htdocs folder. Actually "String cannot be converted to JSONObject error.." was the json response error