# Android client is not connecting to local server ActionScript 3.0 AIR

Tags: android, actionscript, connection, client, wifi

Everything works just fine on the same machine, no errors, nothing. But if I start the client app from Android, it is not connecting anymore. It was working fine yesterday. I do not know what happened. If it is an issue with policy file, I am not getting any warnings. I can't even connect to debugger.
If this is related to security policy file can anyone tell me where should I store the file on my computer to access it with Security.loadPolicyFile("http:/ / 127.0. 0. 1: 81/crossdomain.xml");?
Please, help. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301560/java-net-connectexception-127-0-0-18080-an-android-emulator

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Anyway, the other one is about java and I see no relationship. I still need help

Comment: The other question was about running on the Android emulator. I assume that is what you are trying do? If, instead, you are trying to run the Android app on a physical device, then you must use the actual address of the server, not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: The client is running on Android device. I have the correct local IP of the Wifi connection. The client won't even connect to debugger now.