# unable to connect to localhost

Tags: android, localhost

I have a problem in my android app, it gives an error message saying:- `error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.httphostconnectexception connection to ....://127.0.0.1 refused`.

How can I use this address?

Comment: make sure that you have mentioned these permissions in manifest file..
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1/::1/"localhost" as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6484290/1777090)

Comment: I have corrected my mainifest file but, it produces a new error with error message. "Error in http connection android.od.networkOnMainThreadException" "Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null" Help me more pls?? Thank you in advance for your early replay!!

Comment: please update your code and logcat for which line it shows error.

Comment: I think this can help you :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/2301648/3837191